# How to avoid unwanted Spaces in \NewDocumentEnvironment?

Tags: spacing, environments, xparse

I tried to make my own "quote"-Environment and I wanted the first Letter to be bold and a little bit bigger than the rest. As `\lettrine` doesn't work the way i wanted, i tried to code it on my own.

Everything works as intended, except one thing: I get a white space between the `L` and the `orem Ipsum` and i don't know where it comes from

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,listof=totoc,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citecolor}{HTML}{6495ED} 

% Weil ich parameter im end-teil haben will
\usepackage{xparse}

% Eigene Quotes
\usepackage{csquotes}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myquote}{m o}{%
    \begin{samepage}%
        \list{}{%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}%
            \setlength{\rightmargin}{1.5em}%
            \setlength{\topsep}{0em}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
            \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
            \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
        }%
        \item\relax%
        \begin{itshape}%
            % Anführungszeichen
            \begin{large}\textbf{\textcolor{citecolor}{\flqq}}\end{large}
            % Großer Buchstabe (wenn angegeben)
            \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{{\Large{\textbf#2}}}%
}{%
            \begin{large}\textbf{\textcolor{citecolor}{\frqq}}\end{large}
        \end{itshape}%
        \endlist%
        % Quelle
        \hspace*{\fill}\mbox{\footnotesize\textcolor{citecolor}{\cite{#1}}}%
        \vspace{1.5em}%
    \end{samepage}%
}%



\begin{document}

% Calling the Environment
\begin{myquote}{WIKI1}[L]
orem Ipsum...
\end{myquote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing the `%` required to end lines: as you've not used `\ExplSyntaxOn` the 'standard' requires of TeX programming apply.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Ty for the quick Response, but even if I end each line with a `%`, the blank between the `L` and the `orem Ipsum` stays.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: ty for the hint, i posted a executeable version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space is the end of line after `\begin{myquote}{WIKI1}[L]`, because your "begin part" starts a paragraph and this space is not ignored. The solution is to add `\ignorespaces`.

I've made some other changes to your definition; avoid `\begin{itshape}` or `\begin{large}`: `\itshape` and `\large` are declarations that don't take an argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,listof=totoc,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citecolor}{HTML}{6495ED} 

% Weil ich parameter im end-teil haben will
\usepackage{xparse}

% Eigene Quotes
\usepackage{csquotes}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myquote}{m o}
 {%
  \par
  \begin{samepage}%
  \list{}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}%
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{1.5em}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0em}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
  }%
  \item\relax
  \itshape
  % Anführungszeichen
  {\large\bfseries\textcolor{citecolor}{\flqq}}%
  % Großer Buchstabe (wenn angegeben)
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{{\Large\bfseries#2}}%
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {%
  {\large\bfseries\textcolor{citecolor}{\frqq}}%
  \endlist
  % Quelle
  \hspace*{\fill}\mbox{\footnotesize\textcolor{citecolor}{\cite{#1}}}%
  \vspace{1.5em}%
  \end{samepage}%
 }

\begin{document}

% Calling the Environment
\begin{myquote}{WIKI1}[L]
orem Ipsum...
\end{myquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the additional input! I will apply your improvements to my code! :-)

Answer (score 4):

The space after the `L` is from the newline after `[L]` in your document. You can ignore white space there by adding `\ignorespaces` to your definition. There are also some missing `%` which cause extra space after your grey `<<`

```
            \begin{large}\textbf{\textcolor{citecolor}{\flqq}}\end{large}%<<
            % Großer Buchstabe (wenn angegeben)
            \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{{\Large{\textbf#2}}}%
\ignorespaces}{%
 %%%%%%%%%%
            \begin{large}\textbf{\textcolor{citecolor}{\frqq}}\end{large}%<<
```

Comment: ty very much, now i get it, it wasnt in the definition but in the call